# Order by date time with AM PM

Tags: mysql

I want to write a select query with order by datetime field. my datetime field is in the following format

```
 2014-04-21 05:30 PM
 2014-04-21 06:30 AM
 2014-04-21 10:30 AM
```

I am trying the following, but it's not working

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table 
 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date_time`,'%h.%i%p')
```

Comment: The best solution is to stop storing datetime values as strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the date in proper format by using DATETIME, this makes life easier.
However in your case you can do as

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY date_format(STR_TO_DATE(`date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/860c67/7)**

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use the correct format string ;)

```
 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(`date_time`,'%Y-%c-%e %h:%i %p')
```

See for example in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4181d/6).

[Reference.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) (search for "The following specifiers may be used in the format string. The “%” character is required before format specifier characters." that brings up the table of available format string values)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_time,'%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p')
```